# Publishing raster image as tiles?

Tags: raster, web-mapping, tiles

I have a full world image (raster) that I would like to make available, such that I can use it with a leaflet.js based web page. I have looked at GeoServer and MapServer, but from what I can tell these are more oriented towards taking vector data and serving them as tiles?

How should I go about making my image available for this use? For one of the images (jpeg), its file size is 690MB.

Comment: Not sure why you've come to that conclusion, both GeoServer and MapServer will happily serve raster data.

Comment: Depending on your needs, a map tiling service such as Mapbox may be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to upload a map service with a portal or arcgis online connection there is an option for a tiled map service when you upload the map service.